# Is there a way to check the visibility of the status bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, statusbar

I have a service that should check periodically visibility of status bar, when some top activity is (or not) in fullscreen mode.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally I have discovered how to check if statusbar is visible or not. Its some kind of hack, but it works for me. I created that method in my Service:

```
private void createHelperWnd() {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams p = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        p.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY;
        p.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
        p.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
        p.width = 1;
        p.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        p.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;
        helperWnd = new View(this); //View helperWnd;

        wm.addView(helperWnd, p);
        final ViewTreeObserver vto = helperWnd.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                if (heightS == helperWnd.getHeight()) {
                    isFullScreen = true;
                } else {
                    isFullScreen = false;
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

where widthS and heightS our global screen size;
Here I just compared invisible helper window height to screen height and make decision if status bar is visible. And do not forget to remove helperWnd in onDestroy of your Service.

Comment: I came up with a similar method to yours on my own, except overriding onSizeChanged... in my testing I've found our methods do not work on all devices.  It works fine on all API10+ AVDs and a Moto Atrix2, but does not work on Kindle Fire API10 & SGS2 API15.  On these devices the overlays do not auto-resize when another app goes full screen, nor can the overlays be drawn over the status bar without the FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN.  Have you encountered this and/or found a better/alternate solution?  TIA!

Comment: @deviant, how you get 'heightS' on tablet? Please give this code

Answer (score 4):

hello and if you try this code that provides android as good practice

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
        (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
        // Note that system bars will only be "visible" if none of the
        // LOW_PROFILE, HIDE_NAVIGATION, or FULLSCREEN flags are set.
        if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
            // TODO: The system bars are visible. Make any desired
            // adjustments to your UI, such as showing the action bar or
            // other navigational controls.
        } else {
            // TODO: The system bars are NOT visible. Make any desired
            // adjustments to your UI, such as hiding the action bar or
            // other navigational controls.
        }
    }
});
```

I leave the link of the documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility#java

Answer (score 3):

```
public boolean isStatusBarVisible() {
    Rect rectangle = new Rect();
    Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
    window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle);
    int statusBarHeight = rectangle.top;
    return statusBarHeight != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really. If it is *your* activity in the foreground, your activity could tell the service if it is using a theme that hides the status bar. You have no way of determining this independently from the service though, let alone for third-party activities rather than your own.

Comment: I have discovered getSystemUiVisibility() method. Documentation says that it is what I need. But seems its not working. return result always 0 :(

Comment: SystemUI listeners work just fine, but they only tell you on Honeycomb and above when the software buttons hide (in Honeycomb this is never).

Comment: @deviant in my experimentation with getSystemUiVisibility it does not report SystemUI visibility if an app has gone full screen, only if another app has used the setSystemUiVisibility flags available in API11+ (still experimenting though).  Have you found otherwise?