# Detect Status Bar Visibility / TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY not resizing automatically

Tags: android, layout, parameters

I'm using the well known `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` method to create a full screen overlay that's always on top of other views.

On a `Moto Atrix2 API15` and for each `AVD` from `API 10` through `17` the overlay view resizes automatically (expands vertically) when the status bar is hidden by another app.  The overlay appears to "stay on top" of all other views, as I think it should.  When the status bar is in view again, the overlay reduces it's size automatically again (less vertical pixels, basically subtracting the height of the status bar).

This is the desired behavior and am inclined to think this is not the exception or flawed behavior due to it working on many different emulators as well as at least one device manufacturer (*motorola*), perhaps more, but I don't have access to `addtl devices.`

**The problem:**  On a `Samsung GS2 (API15)` & also tested on `Kindle Fire (API10?)`, the overlay does not automatically resize (fill the space where the status bar once was) when the status bar is hidden by another app (status bar behind full screen app).  On these devices, after the view is created the first time I don't get any more events from an onSizeChanged override for the view.

Here's the pertinent code:

```
params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams( 
    1, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
    |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, 
    PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
wm.addView(sizeLayout, params);
```

sizeLayout has the onSizeChanged override.

I've played around with just about every `windowmanager` `layoutparam` I can find, including SYSTEM_ALERT, FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN, etc.  I won't sleep until I can figure this out!

**Edit 11/30/12**: I found this from @deviant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9195733/1851478 which is basically what I'm doing, however the problem remains with certain devices not resizing the system_overlay automatically.  Perhaps I should raise a bug.

More INFO: IF I force a redraw (or even just load the overlay app) while there is a full screen app at the top of the view tree, my overlay still does not draw over the space the status bar normally takes up (even though the status bar is not in view at the time of draw), so it seems as if the overlay is not "overlayed" on top of the frontmost window which is full screen (and I've both created and tested many full screen apps using a variety of methods to make them go full screen).  On these devices, the only way to get the overlay to draw over the status bar (even if the status bar is not in view) is to use the flag `FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN`, but then the size of the layout never changes, is always full screen, and thus back to the original problem why this works on some devices but not others.

***Edit 12/12/12***:  So I haven't had any further luck on this, and I did try using getLocalVisibleRect on views, but unfortunately since my app doesn't own the SystemUI views it can't detect what's below the overlays.  I suppose with a custom ROM I could do this, but I need a solution without root.

I do see other apps on the marketplace are having the same problem detecting the status bar on the non-working phones I listed above.  Example: cool tool, omega statusbar & status bar +.  Bounty raised.

***Edit 12/19/12*** Pictures added.  Note that on a working device the gray area also "covers" the black area (any app that is currently full screen), the black area actually covers entire screen, I'm just showing the gray area as my overlay even though it is also full screen (minus or plus the height of the status bar depending on working/non-working device and whether it is in view or not).

[image]       [image]

Comment: can you please add screen shots of the needed behavior and what you are getting ?

Comment: have you tried to turn to full screen ? before adding your view try :
 // go full screen
    WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = mActivity.getWindow().getAttributes();
    attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    mActivity.getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);

Comment: @Anis, Yes I've tried the full_screen flag and get the same behavior.  However, your question indicates perhaps you don't fully grasp the problem, and I suggest that you read it again.  Thanks for the idea though! :)

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully i understand what you are after here but, in my app (TEAM BatteryBar) i had a similar problem. ( no root minimal permissions )

I couldn't detect a full screen on anything below API11 (and intermittent on some (Samsung mostly) devices above API11). So i made a custom listener for it by adding a second layout to the WindowManager with a different layout param then overrode the onLayout to check if the statusBar is still there or not by checking the window size. from there you can do what ever you need to to your main view.

I was going to tidy it up but it worked so i didn't :P  code is over a year old and is from when i first started coding for android so yeah. Food for thought tho. hope it helps.

[here is the code in a repo at my github](https://github.com/pvyParts/Android-Helpers) with a copy paste straight out of my app on how i am using it. small snippet here

```
wm.addView(sizeLayout, params);// add your view

// then add the next one
Screendetect mDetector;
mDetector = new Screendetect(this);
mDetector.setOnFullScreenListener(new OnFullScreenListener() {
            @Override
            public void fsChanged(boolean FS_Bool) {
                // TODO rethink this to be better.... bit hacky...
                if (FS_Bool) {
                    Log.d("battbardetect", "Statusbar hidden");
                    FS_vissible(); // do what ever you need to
                } else if (!FS_Bool) {
                    Log.d("battbardetect", "Statusbar Vissible"); 
                    FS_hidden(); // do what ever you need to
                }
            }
        });
wm.addView(mDetector, params);
```

Comment: I will try OnFullScreenListener, but basically your answer is just re-wording/doing the same thing I have already tried, and what I have documented does not work on all devices.  It works on some, but not others (seemingly without explanation).  On the non-working devices your method (and mine/deviants) do not seem to be detecting the overlay resize automatically, whether it's using OnFullScreenListener, OnGlobalLayoutListener, or overriding onSizeChanged on the overlay layout.

Comment: I looked at your code and you are just overriding onLayout, which I've already tried without success on the non-working devices.  In my example/question I override onSizeChanged and tried overriding just about every view method I could within an inflated overlay layout (pretty much just the same as you did).

Comment: Ok thanks for trying. I tried your code, pretty much word for word and same problem, onLayout is only called once when the view is first added (or on configuration change), and not again until the service (or view) is destroyed/removed and created/added again.  And even if I repeatedly add and remove the view the vertical size never changes unless I add the layout in screen flag.  So basically same problems, at least as tested on a Samsung GS2 API15.  BTW onSystemUiVisibilityChange doesn't work either.  I don't get any events from that: the GS2 device is ICS with physical navigation keys.

Comment: Oh, and BTW I tried your battery bar app on the Samsung GS2 and your app has the same problem, it's not able to detect a full screen app (guessing yours would have the same issue on a Kindle Fire if you published there).

Comment: Interesting, is it a certain/select few Full screen apps or is it all of them? ( i noticed i had forgotten to add an option for the legacy detection on the Free version, i was gonna update tonight ) *Edit* Possible bug in Samsung firmware? as my Sony API15 works with both.

Comment: Yes any full screen app (even wrote several of my own to try different methods of setting full screen, doesnt matter how, and doesn't matter which example youtube/etc.).  Yes I am thinking possible bug in the Samsung FW, but it also happens on a Kindle Fire, so it starts to make me wonder...

Comment: Ok, one of my mates has a S2 i'll get him to come over and have a play. kindle fire runs a modified API10(GB) or API15(ICS) (i think)so the bug could have come from the AOSP tree.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be the same issue with hiding the titlebar on dialog windows where the system sets the visibility to hidden instead of gone. This causes the dialog window to get incorrectly centered.

For that, here's how I fix it. This might work for your situation but you may need to adjust it for the name of the status bar identifier.

```
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
View view = window.getDecorView();
int topPanelId = getResources().getIdentifier("topPanel", "id", "android");
LinearLayout topPanel = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(topPanelId);
topPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: I fairly certain this will require root (and perhaps a custom SystemUI.apk), and I need a solution without either of those.  Secondarily I'm not really interested in hiding the status bar, just detecting whether it's visible or not.  I'll play around with this some, but I'm not hopeful.

Comment: I didn't have any success setting the visibility of a view my app doesn't own... thanks for trying.